# Spoof DNS in a Rogue AP

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

I am using 2 interfaces on my computer, eth0 grants access to the outside world and wlan0 is where the Access Point is set up.

My configuration is based on 2 networks 192.168.1.0 on eth0 and 10.0.0.0 on wlan0.
I have a dhcp server that hands IP's for the network 10.0.0.0 and there, I have as DNS my ip of wlan0 (10.0.0.1) and 8.8.8.8.

When I connect with other device to the network, everything works fine, I have my IP address, I am redirected to the outside world from wlan0 to eth0 by iptables BUT I want to spoof the DNS. And here is my doubt.
How do I do that¿? I have read about dnsmasq, working as both DHCP server and DNS, but on my config, what would be the interface of the DNS, wlan0¿?

I hope I made myself clear, if anyone can help me I would really appreciate, and I would also appreciate if someone could through some light with this. I am a little bit confused on how a DNS server on a wlan0 interface that has no access to the internet can act as DNS.

Answer (score 1):

It should be wlan0. Your setup should open up port 53 on the wlan0. Once a client makes a DNS resolution request, the DNS server should recursively resolve it using the regular Internet path (eth0).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So to make sure I understood:
My DNS are resolved acording to the file /etc/resolv, there I have 192.168.1.1 (where I am connected through eth0), so, I don't have a DNS server, when users connect to my access point, their DNS are gonna be resolve by 192.168.1.1, but, if I have a DNS server on wlan0, the users that connect to me, uses with priority my "hosts" example, if I have 10.0.0.1 facebook.com, when they go to facebook they go to my IP, and for the rest IPs they use my /etc/resolv don't they¿? Thank u

Comment: Mostly. But for the part where the DNS needs to be resolved, you need to have a DNS server. All DNS queries on wlan0 will be resolved only then. And to resolve the DNS queries, the DNS recursive server (like djbdns or BIND) will make independent *recursive* queries (unrelated to your local resolver, as in /etc/resolv.conf).